# Winter Bash 2014: A Community Thing

Tags: discussion, fun, winterbash

In case you <s>are living on another planet</s> *weren't aware*, [Winter Bash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) is on, which means we get to collect hats until January 4<sup>th</sup>.

Once again this year, Code Review is ranked above every other beta site, among the [best hat-collecting SE sites](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) (currently 14<sup>th</sup>).

Sure, you can collect hats for yourself, and increase your own personal [SE-wide ranking](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network). But...

**Let's get Code Review to the top!** (well, let's shoot for the top-10 all right?)

What can we do, as a community, to ***get moar hatz***?

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget [to join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) where if you 'star' enough messages you can participate in (and evaluate) the wrestling of the big guys ([Sumo Judge](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/sumo-judge))!!!

Answer (score 5):

We could... <s>mass-downvote anyone that isn't wearing a hat...</s>

Nah. Seriously, some hats are easy to get - you can get a [not-so-]secret hat ([HairBoat](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/hairboat)) on Code Review, by commenting on [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/73995/23788).

Comment: Well, mass-downvoting also gets people hats.

Comment: How does commenting on the post you mentioned get you a hat?

Comment: @MannyMeng because, unicorns :)

Answer (score 4):

Help clean up the site. Editing (even suggested edits that get approved) 5 old posts will get you a [Tardis!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245270/256822) But shhhhh that's a (not so) [secret hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats).

Answer (score 2):

"Business in the front, Party in the back" is a good way to go... Just be fair and vote the poor guy back up again. D̷o̷e̷s̷ ̷i̷t̷ ̷l̷o̷o̷k̷ ̷l̷i̷k̷e̷ ̷I̷ ̷v̷o̷l̷u̷n̷t̷e̷e̷r̷i̷n̷g̷?̷